# How to add a trailing end of line to AttribueList using Roslyn CTP

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation, roslyn

I am trying to generate a few properties with `[DataContractAttribute]` using Roslyn CTP Syntax. Unfortunately, Roslyn puts the attribute on the same line as the property.

Here is what I get:

```
[DataContract]public int Id { get; set; }
[DataContract]public int? Age { get; set; }
```

What I would like to achieve:

```
[DataContract]
public int Id { get; set; }
[DataContract]
public int? Age { get; set; }
```

Generator's code:

```
string propertyType = GetPropertyType();
string propertyName = GetPropertyName();
var property = Syntax
    .PropertyDeclaration(Syntax.ParseTypeName(propertyType), propertyName)
    .WithModifiers(Syntax.TokenList(Syntax.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword)))
    .WithAttributeLists(
        Syntax.AttributeList(
            Syntax.SeparatedList<AttributeSyntax>(
                Syntax.Attribute(Syntax.ParseName("DataContract")))))
    .WithAccessorList(
        Syntax.AccessorList(
            Syntax.List(
                Syntax.AccessorDeclaration(SyntaxKind.GetAccessorDeclaration)
                    .WithSemicolonToken(Syntax.Token(SyntaxKind.SemicolonToken)),
                Syntax.AccessorDeclaration(SyntaxKind.SetAccessorDeclaration)
                    .WithSemicolonToken(Syntax.Token(SyntaxKind.SemicolonToken))
        )));
```

After wrapping those properties in a class, a namespace and finally CompilationUnit, I am using the following code to get the string result:

```
var compUnit = Syntax.CompilationUnit().WithMembers(...);
IFormattingResult fResult = compUnit.Format(new FormattingOptions(false, 4, 4));
string result = fResult.GetFormattedRoot().GetText().ToString();
```

Comment: How do you convert the result to `string`?

Comment: @svick I updated my question with how I retrieve the string result

Comment: I think the cleanest (but probably not simplest) solution would be to implement `IFormattingRule` and use that in your `Format()` call. But I couldn't figure out how to implement that properly.

Comment: Formatting rules are overkill here. Just generate your original node with the newline. The formatter should keep it around.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski I have tried adding TrailingTrivia(Syntax.EndOfLine) to AttributeList, to Attribute, etc. - without effect.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski I tried adding trailing trivia to the `AttributeList`, but the formatter seems to be removing it.

Comment: Minor update: RC version of Roslyn has SyntaxFactory class, instead on Syntax. I recoment recheck solution and refresh it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this would to format your code and then modify it by adding trailing trivia to all property attribute lists. Something like:

```
var formattedUnit = (SyntaxNode)compUnit.Format(
    new FormattingOptions(false, 4, 4)).GetFormattedRoot();

formattedUnit = formattedUnit.ReplaceNodes(
    formattedUnit.DescendantNodes()
                 .OfType<PropertyDeclarationSyntax>()
                 .SelectMany(p => p.AttributeLists),
    (_, node) => node.WithTrailingTrivia(Syntax.Whitespace("\n")));

string result = formattedUnit.GetText().ToString();
```

Comment: It works and properties are on the new lines, but unfortunately they lost their indentations. However, I can add those by appending desired indentation after "\n", so I have what I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Use it like below:

```
.WithTrailingTrivia(SyntaxFactory.ElasticCarriageReturnLineFeed)
```